# Issues deserializing JSON response

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I get the following response when calling an API (this is expected; it's part of a functional test for handling a bad query):

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 17:43:39 GMT
>   Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=5/5000 Content-Type:
>   application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> 16F [{"message":"\nSELECT id, name, description FROM BadObject\n
>   ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:35\nsObject type 'BadObject' is not
>   supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or
>   the describe call for the appropriate
>   names.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}] 0

I'm trying to deserialize it into the following class:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string message;
    public string errorCode;
}
```

Using the following code:

```
var errorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(response);
```

However, when I try to deserialize it, I get the following error:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Salesforce.Common.Models.ErrorResponse' because the type requires a
>   JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON
>   object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."}

I suspect it's the \n (newline) causing issues. I've tried replacing "\n" with "\n" but it hasn't worked.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the JSON is surrounded by square brackets, it's an array. You'll need to deserialize into an object that accepts multiple entries. For example:

```
public class ErrorResponses : List<ErrorResponse> { }

public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string message;
    public string errorCode;
}
```

Then you can deserialize like so:

```
var errorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponses>( json );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you did, you just need to deserialize it into a List<ErrorResponse> instead of ErrorResponse.